# Adding dataTypes to jQuery.ajax?

Tags: jquery

jQuery.ajax({dataType:...}) supports several known dataTypes (xml, json,jsonp, script,text, or html).

Is there a way to add your own datatype handlers like:

```
var wcf = function(data){...}

jQuery.ajax({dataType:wcf, ...});
```

Obviously I've already tried this, and it doesn't work. But is there another way?

Comment: Not really sure there is a WCF data type. If you need to understand how to work against WCF with jQuery I have several posts about it. http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/02/08/Using-JQuery-and-JSON-to-Interact-with-a-WCF-Service-via-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a clean way to do this, at least not as far as jQuery 1.4.4 simply because there are tons of `if()` checks inside `$.ajax()` that rely on datatypes, and *that's* how they're currently "supported".  However, jQuery 1.4.5 will have some interesting changes here.

If you're curious, you can browse github for the latest and see how jQuery AJAX behavior is being made *much* more extensible by dividing the transport code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/transports

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own implementation of jQuery.ajax function, like:

```
(function($) {
    var ajax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(o) {
        // perform some custom logic here...
        var result = ajax.apply(this, arguments);
        // ...and here
        return result;
    }
});
```